# How to show the non-participants in each division?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am developing an intranet web application that provides the users with short quizzes.
The question is: I have the following database design:

Employee Table: Username, Name, Job, DivisionID

Division Table: DivisionID, DivisionName

Quiz Table: QuizID, Title, Description

UserQuiz Table: UserQuizID, Score, DateTimeComplete, QuizID, Username

***NOTE: The first attribute in each table is the primary key.***

I need to come up with a query that shows:

- the names of non-participants
- Division
- Total number of non-participants

**So How to do that?**

Answer (score 2):

This query gives you a list of users which have not participated in any quiz:

```
SELECT Name, DivisionName FROM Employee AS E
LEFT OUTER JOIN Division AS D ON E.DivisionID = D.DivisionID
WHERE Username NOT IN (SELECT Username FROM UserQuiz)
```

This gives you the number of non-participants:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Employee
WHERE Username NOT IN (SELECT Username FROM UserQuiz)
```

UPDATES to answer questions in comments:

To group and count non-paraticipants per quiz and division:

```
SELECT Q.QuizId, D.DivisionName, E.Name FROM Quiz AS Q
CROSS JOIN Employee AS E
LEFT OUTER JOIN Division AS D ON E.DivisionID = D.DivisionID
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM UserQuiz AS UQ 
    WHERE UQ.Username = E.Username AND UQ.QuizID = Q.QuizID)
ORDER BY Q.QuizId, D.DivisionName
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and I really appreciate it. And by the way, can I merge both of them and have a one query that shows all the above requirements?

Comment: You can add the COUNT(*) as a column after name and DivisionName. But that will give you the same value repeated on each row returned, so I think it will be better to have a separate query. You can also count number of rows returns in the code which receives the data, so it will not be necessary to combine them.

Comment: Thanks. but how to show the non-participants names in each quiz. I mean, I want to retrieve the QuizID. The results should be grouped by DivisionName and QuizID. How to do that?